WP theme edit add a link to a button
I have a button in WP header that does not work correctly.
I trying to add a link to a "Book Online" button that by pressing button it goes to /contact-us/ permalink page. Can you advice how to add code correctly?
Here is a PHP code WP Theme editor:
<?php
wp_nav_menu(array(
    'theme_location'  => 'menu-1',
    'depth'           => 2, // 1 = no dropdowns, 2 = with dropdowns.
    'container'       => 'div',
    'container_class' => 'mr-auto',
    'container_id'    => '',
    'menu_class'      => 'navbar-nav mt-2 mt-lg-0',
    'fallback_cb'     => 'WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker::fallback',
    'walker'          => new WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker(),
));
?>
<form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
    <div class="headrig"> <span><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/call.png"><?php echo get_option('theme_option_phone_no'); ?></span> <button type="button" class="btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">BOOK ONLINE</button></div>
</form>


Use an <a href="..."> to link to a page? Set a form action and use a submit button?

Existing code:
<button type="button" class="btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">BOOK ONLINE</button>

Convert to:
<a href="/contact-us/" class="btn-primary" >BOOK ONLINE</a>


How exactly do the two differ? None of those goes to the /contact-us/ page

if yo want to go on /contact-us/ then use this:
BOOK ONLINE

Thank For reply. This seems html code and it does not have button assigned ?

I'm looking to assign button in php to go to https://www.flatpack-handyman.co.uk/contact-us/      Please let me know the correct code

You have to try this: BOOK ONLINE
